# How to type the @ sign in a web browser from a Spanish keyboard

Tags: firefox, keyboard, microsoft-edge, input-languages

I'm trying to setup a new Dell PC for use with Spanish keyboard settings.  The ESP keyboard layout doesn't have an @ sign on it, but websites like Outlook.com require me to type that character as part of the user ID when logging in.  What should I do?

Things I've tried:

1. Type Alt-064 or Alt-64 at the login prompt for Outlook.com.  This is the base use case which keeps failing for me, and while it works in notepad, when I try this in Edge or Firefox it appears to tell the browser to change windows instead.
2. I've seen some sites that claim you can get to the at-sign when keyboard is set to ESP by using some combination of Alt and Ctrl keys with the number 2, but I've tried all the variants I can think of and none seem to work.
3. I've verified that authentication can work if I set the language to ENG and use a US keyboard, but that won't be an adequate long-term solution because the eventual end user is a latinx person who needs the ESP layout.

Have I missed something?

Comment: What happens if you type it in notepad, then copy  it from notepadand paste it to outlook.com?

Comment: the copy'paste trick works sometimes, but Microsoft seems to block it out on some of its login pages.  I ran into that problem specifically with a password-reset page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>  for International Spanish.
 <kbd>AltGr</kbd>   <kbd>Q</kbd>  for South American Spanish.

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/where-is-the-at-sign-on-the-spanish-keyboard/babccecd-d692-422b-962f-026a47a64a65

Comment: Am assuming based on the link that "AltGr" is equivalent to "Alt" on my keyboard, it looks like the correct sequence is Alt+Ctrl+2 International or Alt+Ctrl+Q for Latin America.  
... and this was my problem.  I am using an International keyboard with Dominican keyboard language selected in Windows.

Comment: AltGr seems to be recognised the same as Ctrl+Alt on Windows for most purposes. They're technically distinct, but I think Win convention is to make them equivalent.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Q worked with Dominican settings in Windows, but the *real* fix was to change my Windows settings to Spanish (Spain), which is apparently what they call "International", and matched my keyboard.  If I select that language, all the special keys on my keyboard work properly.  Realizing that there were multiple Spanish keyboards made all the difference..